# Can a BufferedImage be written to file any format?

Tags: java, png, jpeg, bufferedimage

Is it correct that if we have a BufferedImage object in java, we could potentially write it out in ANY format using ImageIO.write (if we have a Writer object for the same)? I tried writing a BufferedImage object into a jpg file, it outputted an empty image file however when i tried writing it in to a png file, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

A BufferedImage can be written into any format that ImageIO.write supports (that is, has an ImageWriter available), yes. Please show the code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Hey, I think i diagnosed the problem. For my images the Image Type is TYPE_USHORT_GRAY, and they use 16 bits per sample to represent the data. I dont think jpeg supports 16 bits per sample, it supports just 8 (as all 8 bits per sample images write to disk as jpg correctly). I read that PNG and TIFF support 16 bits per sample so seems to work fine when i write them as PNG (or TIFF). Could this be a plausible reason? Again, not too sure why empty files are being written and an exception is not thrown?

Comment: I think the ImageWriter ought to do any needed conversions. But then again, I could be wrong! But please post the code if you need further help.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka How about into WMF/EMF?

Comment: @SelcukBozdag I don't know. Just try it out.